# Xcode broken on macOS 11.1

Tags: xcode, macos, homebrew, macos-big-sur

**Your Xcode does not support macOS 11.1. It is either outdated or was modified. Please update your Xcode or delete it if no updates are available.**

Every time I try to install **brew install k3d** ,this happens .

I'm using macOS 11.1 with Xocde 12.2.

Comment: Even though Xcode is related to programming, this questions belongs on [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: Download the appropriate [XCode CLT](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/) for your system and your k3d install will work as expected [as shown here](https://habd.as/post/kubernetes-macos-k3s-k3d-rancher/#install-k3s-using-k3d).